# Can't get passed Setup Wizard after Factory Reset cause Google Play Services keeps stopping!

Tags: google-play-store, 5.1-lollipop, tablet, google-play-services, lenovo

after Factory Resetting my **Lenovo Tab 2 A8-50F** Tablet with **Android 5.1** i can't get passed the Setup Wizard after selecting the WIFI you want to connect it.. After Checking the Connection then it's doing a Software Update then **Google Play Services** keeps stopping every time, then revert me back to the WIFI selection screen and loops again and again. What can i do to fix this?
i tried Resetting it again but no luck and there is no option to Clear the Cache from the Boot Menu!!!

Comment: First thing to do is to determine the device platform, I mean the CPU inside the device. Is this a Mediatek or Qualcomm model?

Comment: The BB-Chip says MT6735 so Mediatek probably. and this must be his  [Firmware](https://firmwarefile.com/lenovo-tab-2-a8-50f)

Comment: any idea where to find the drivers??

Comment: On the internet obviously :D . Well the firmware usually contains necessary drivers. If does not: https://androidmtk.com/download-mtk-usb-all-drivers

Comment: yeah :P i found some but it says it's for a MT8161 Chip thats why i'm asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is probably a corrupted system files resulted from the reset. Flashing the firmware should solve  this.

Depending on the hardware platform, you'll need tools to flash the device. This phone comes with two variants: the one with Qualcomm chipset and the other with Mediatek chipset.

For your case the chip is a Mediatek MT6735 , you need [SP Flash tool](http://spflashtool.com/) and [ROM](https://firmwarefile.com/lenovo-tab-2-a8-50f) file for the phone exact model. Don't forget to install [Mediatek USB and Preloader drivers](https://androidmtk.com/download-mtk-usb-all-drivers) otherwise the device won't be determined by the computer. Then follow the flashing process.